# MultiTree count the leaves (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

The function for counting leaves if you have a binary tree is e.g.:

```
> leaves ' :: (Tree a) -> [a]
> leaves ' b = lvl b []
>              where lvl Nil as = as
>                    lvl (Leaf a) as = a:as
>                    lvl (Br l r) as = lvl l (lvl r as)
```

Now I have to do the same with Multitrees (rose trees). It should start with

> multileaves :: MultiTree a -> [a]

My first idea was something like

```
> data MultiTree a = Nil
>       | Leaf a
>       | Br [MultiTree a]  deriving Show

> multileaves :: MultiTree a -> [a]
> multileaves b = lvl b []
>             where lvl Nil as = as
>               lvl (Leaf a) as = a:as
>               lvl (Br a) as = Br a (map (multileaves (a:b) as)
```

But Hugs says it's may a bad layout.

I'm overwhelmed. Ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: For future posts, please include the definitions of your data types as well, these can often be very useful for identifying what the problem is and how to solve it.  Currently, it looks like your code won't type check because of `(a:b)`, since unless `type MultiTree a = [a]`, you can't prepend an element to the front of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's basically two things you need to make sure so a Haskell program even parses:

- Matching brackets. Should be obvious enough, yet your example's last line has 3 open and only 2 closing parens. Make it

  ```
          Br a (map (multileaves (a:b) as))
  ```

  or (preferred)

  ```
          Br a . map $ multileaves (a:b) as
  ```
- Indentation. Let's forget about tabs, these are evil – turn them off in your editor / IDE. (Any proper editor should also make mismatching brackets obvious, BTW!)
  What you need to make sure is that the next local binding in a `where` or `let`, the next statement in a `do` block, or the next case in a `case` select, are *as many spaces indented as there are characters to the left of the first such statement*. In your case, if you have the line

  ```
       where lvl Nil as = as
  ```

  then the next one needs to be indented so the `lvl` is aligned with the previous one, like in the original `leaves'`.

Once your program parses, you'll find other problems:

- `b` is *the entire tree* you work on. You re-refer to that in each single recursion step, that's obviously getting you in an infinite loop. I don't know why you think you'd need `:` at all; `a` is apparently already a list for you `Multitree` type. You just want to map over that list.
- The result type is all wrong. You need a list here, yet you're constructing a tree again.

Comment: Thanks for your advices. What do you mean with the wrong result type, have you a suggestion?

Comment: I mean, if your type signature says you return a list then why do you construct a tree! — I could of course tell you how to do it, but why don't you first try it yourself? As a hint: you may find it useful to [Hoogle for this type signature](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=[[a]]+-%3E+[a]), or alternatively [that one](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+[b]%29+-%3E+[a]+-%3E+[b]).

Comment: Okay. And what's wrong if hugs tells me "Error: Equations give different arities for "lvl"" ? Is it also because I fault in the last line or is that something I overlook?

Comment: That error message is self-explanatory enough. Apparently, you removed something on the left of the `=` and now have only one argument; why did you do that?

Comment: I think because I'm just too stupid for this. Did not even notice that I have left out something. There's no error now, hopefully I got it. Thanks for your patience and help!

Comment: Don't despair, with some more practise you'll see through these kind of errors yourself soon!

Answer (score 4):

You have to indent the last two lines starting with `lvl` to the same point as the `lvl` in the line above

```
multileaves b = lvl b []
    where lvl Nil as = as
          lvl (Leaf a) as = a:as
          lvl (Br a) as = Br a (map (multileaves (a:b) as)
```

Or you can use my preferred form

```
multileaves b = lvl b []
    where
        lvl Nil as = as
        lvl (Leaf a) as = a:as
        lvl (Br a) as = Br a (map (multileaves (a:b) as)
```

---

**EDIT**

After inspecting the text in your post more closely, it looks like you're using tabs for indentations.  This can often lead to problems in Haskell due to whitespace inconsistencies, I would recommend switching to using only spaces.  Your editor should have an option to insert spaces when you hit the tab key, unless you're using notepad.exe.

Comment: Thank you! Now I have my old problem again

Type error in application
*** Expression     : Br a (map (multileaves (a : b)) as)
*** Term           : Br
*** Type           : [MultiTree d] -> MultiTree d
*** Does not match : a -> b -> c

Do you know what to do?

Comment: @leftaroundabout has some good suggestions to help you there.  There are several problems with the actual code itself that I chose not to comment on since your initial problem seemed to be with whitespace.  I was intending that once you got your indentations sorted out you'd be able to see the next error and attempt to figure out your problems from there.  leftaroundabout did spot a paren mismatch that I had missed, though, along with some other type mismatches.